# Multi-item Carousel no display

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I would like to seek help why is my carousel don't display any items. My goal is to display at least 3 item at a time.I already tried adding height but no avail.Please note that the images used here are from google for sampling only.

Here is the JS Fiddel of my code https://jsfiddle.net/nm0f3twc/1

```
<div class="videosliderCarousel">
<div class="carousel slide multi-itemcarousel" id="videoSlider">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="" src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg" class="img-rensponsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="" src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg" class="img-rensponsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="" src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg" class="img-rensponsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="" src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg" class="img-rensponsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="" src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg" class="img-rensponsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <a href="" src="https://www.everythingcarers.org.au/media/1982/sample.jpg" class="img-rensponsive">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Replace your anchor elements with img,

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: @JustLearning Thanks sir i didn't know that anchor tag cannot be used :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your fiddle slightly to show that the carousel does work. So i added default html for the carousel from the bootstrap site:

[fiddle with basic carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/7yc0hm9v/)

As i mentioned in my comment your carousel does not work because you are using `<a>` elements instead of `<img>`